# How to check is property existed in function-object (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, function, object, properties

This question about JavaScript with function-Object.

I have a function like:

```
function person(){
this.name = 'Tom',
this.Age //not set any value
}
```

And I created a object by "person" function:

```
var obj = new person();
obj.name //Tom
obj.Age //undefined
obj.DOB //also returned undefined
```

How to distinguish "Age” property already exist in "obj" but no value, or "DOB" does not exist at all.

Comment: You can set this.Age = null; (null !== undefined)

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript distinguishes between null, which is a value that indicates a deliberate non-value (and is only accessible through the null keyword), and undefined, which is a value of type undefined that indicates an uninitialized value — that is, a value hasn't even been assigned yet.

You can simply use

```
if(this.hasOwnProperty('Age')){

}
```

Or

```
if('Age' in this){

}
```

Comment: Note that these two choices have slightly different behavior.  The second will be true if `Age` is anywhere in the object including in the prototype.  The first will only be true if `Age` is a direct property on the object (and not only on the prototype).

Comment: Also, note that a property can exist, but have an assigned value of `undefined`, so you can't test for `undefined` to see if the property exists or not.  `.hasOwnProperty()` is probably the best choice to test if a given property has been specifically assigned to this object or not.

Comment: Anyway if you do not initialize `'Age'` property, it does not function, so initialization is mandatory

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried use "hasOwnProperty" and "in" to distinguishes. but returned same value is "undefined".

"hasOwnProperty" is only used for normal object in Javascript.

this is a "function-Object" not normal. so its not work.

Answer (score 2):

`obj.Age` is not *already existing*. if you wanted it to then you have to  initialize it to `null` or `undefined` 
then you could check like

```
if(obj.hasOwnProperty('Age')){

}
```

Answer (score -2):

You only want to check for it's existence? Use an `if` statement

```
if (obj.Age) {
  // do stuf
} else {
  // do other stuff
}
```

undefined returns as a falsy value to the if statement, so if it's not there it will execute the else statement. If it does exist, then the first block.

Comment: false, 0, empty strings (""), NaN, null, and undefined all become false.